# Why are my DIVs clearing left?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, xhtml, css-float

I don't usually post a link to my site when asking questions, though I don't see another way around it. I apologize in advance.

I'm having difficulties with a specific page. The page consists of Team Members, where each member is its own DIV (also each team member is coincidentally a separate post in Wordpress).

For some reason, the DIVs wrapping each post are clearing left, but no clearing attributes are assigned!

The page is located here: http://engineercreativity.com/samples/comsense/?page_id=15

Please, if you can help, I'd love to hear any input.

Thanks a lot!
Amit

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific, I'm having trouble understanding how the final result should look like?

Comment: There should not be any significant white spaces below each team member. For example, consider MOTTY DANOS, there is a LOT of white space above him. He's supposed to be directly below Com&Sense: Communications & Strategy.

Comment: The reason there's a lot of white space above him is that the DIV is clearing left. And I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divs are floating on horizontal axis and not vertically, What you are essentially looking for is a Masonry Plugin, its for jquery and should easily solve your problem.

http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/

edit:
your divs are not clearing on left, please see the computed layout
[image]

the whitespace is not because of divs clearing left, the whitespace is because of line height. When you are having two floating elements in a row, then the row will take height equal to the bigger element, so essentially each row will have white space below the smaller div. This is similar to a HTML Table.

Comment: Why do I need a js plugin to solve an (essentially) simple CSS issue? I just don't understand why the DIVs are clearing left. Do you see what I mean? In 3 years of webdesign, I have never had that happen to me before.

Comment: this is not a css issue. If you can, please attach a screenshot and highlight the area which you are pointing to.

Comment: Oh wow that is extremely interesting, I did not know that. Thank you for clarifying! Is this fixable without a js plugin?

Comment: You're totally right. That is exactly the issue. I checked out the plug in and it looks like exactly what I want it to do. I guess the reason I've never run into this problem is because I've always separated the page into two DIVs, and had floating DIVs in those separated to column divs. Either way, thanks man. If there's a CSS fix for this (rather than JS), I'd love to hear it.

Comment: welcome Amit, there is definitely a CSS fix for this. Just have two cols and in wordpress {which i think you are using}, output the divs alternatively in each column.

Answer (score 0):

Akinator's fix didn't work for me in FF on Win XP.  If you change your float on the "team-member" class to float: left it will fix it.  It is being caused by your static image being float left and the rest of the divs around it being float right.

Comment: I tried changing it to float left. I've used Firebug and everything, it doesn't fix it. If you change it to float: left, then it for some reason clears right. Check the page now, I've changed it to float: left;

Comment: And you're right, Ankinator's fix did not work for me either.

Comment: a left float looks a lot better than the right one, but it still clears:right...I guess I can live with that...

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly, you have a `margin-bottom` of 15px in the class `.team-member`, this gives and extra white space.

It should be set to 0 (or not set)

Is this what you ment?
[image]

Comment: What browser are you using? Because I'm not seeing it like that, even after setting a margin-bottom of 0. The extra white space I'm seeing is very very significant, I'll try to post a pic

Comment: I'm using chrome 8 from a mac

Comment: @Amit can I get a link to your modifications? I just want to clarify that this leaves some whitespace at the bottom but solves the div issues (at least in chrome)

Comment: That's a screenshot at how I see with Firefox on Windows 7

Comment: Please disregard the big image at the top. I'm just talking about the image inserted below the words "dedicated page"

Comment: @Amit I'm sorry I have to leave now but I will check it out and come back tomorrow just ins case try this css resets. There might be something strange going on there http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ good luck.

Comment: Okay...I already have a great CSS reset, but I'll try yours. Thanks!